# Passing A Parameter Along with a Function Pointer

Tags: c++, wt

I am using the [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) C++ library in a project. I am trying to use the `connect(...)` function to connect a slot to a button press. The documentation for the `connect(...)` function can be found [here](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1JSignal.html#aab0762fbd02ddda1087b49a35a7c17a6).

Essentially, each time a change is detected in a group of radio buttons, the function passed as a pointer to the `connect(...)` function is called.

Below is a short snippet of the code:

```
...

_group = new Wt::WButtonGroup(this);
Wt::WRadioButton *button;

button = new Wt::WRadioButton("Radio Button 0", this);
_group->addButton(button, 0);

_group->setSelectedButtonIndex(0); // Select the first button by default.

_group->checkedChanged().connect(this, (&MyWidget::RadioButtonToggle)); //Need to pass parameter here  

...
```

I need to pass the `selection` parameter to the function`RadioButtonToggle(Wt::WRadioButton *selection)` so that I can use it in the function body as seen below:

```
void CycleTimesWidget::RadioButtonToggle(Wt::WRadioButton *selection)
{
    switch (_group->id(selection))
    {
        case 0:
    {
            //Do something...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass a parameter along with this function pointer?

Comment: You might want to look into [functors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/10077).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `Wt:WSignalMapper`, documentation can be found [here](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WSignalMapper.html). With a `Wt:WSignalMapper` you can connect multiple senders to a single slot. The multiple senders are in your case the different `Wt:WRadioButton`.

```
Wt::WSignalMapper<Wt:WRadioButton *> * mapper = new Wt::WSignalMapper<
        Wt::WRadioButton *>(this);
mapper->mapped().connect(this, &MyWidget::RadioButtonToggle);

// for all radio buttons
mapper->mapConnect(button->changed(), button);
...
```

You can then use your function `RadioButtonToggle` as written above in your question.

**Update:**

As pointed out in the comments, a `Wt:WSignalMapper` is outdated. You should now use `boost::bind()` or `std::bind()` if you use C++ 11 or higher. The code then becomes:

```
// for all radio buttons
button->changed().connect(boost::bind(this, &MyWidget::RadioButtonToggle, button));
```

Comment: This is great! I did not see this in the documentation. Thanks a lot. Accepted answer.

Comment: WSignalmapper is actually outdated. The shorter, easier, and preferred method is now to use boost::bind(), see FAQ http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q-How-do-I-pass-an-additional-argument-from-a-signal-to-a-slot